# Display image to my osclass website

Tags: php, osclass

i have this function and it echos a banner of 250*250 banner. Now i want to display a image to this content. I cant figure out how i can display images. Can someone help this is my code

```
   if(!function_exists('aiclassy_draw_ad')) {
    function aiclassy_draw_ad(){
        echo '<div class="advertise_area">

        </div>';

        echo ' <br /> <div class="advertise_area">

        </div>';
          echo ' <br /> <div class="advertise_area">

        </div>';
          echo ' <br /> <div class="advertise_area">

        </div>';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the `<img />` HTML element.

In Osclass, you will propbably store your image in your theme (convention is two put images in oc-content/themes/your_theme/assets/img/).

In that case :
`<img src="<?php echo osc_current_web_theme_url("assets/img/your-image.jpg"); ?> alt="alt attribute of your image" />`